# How to calculate number of months if I have starting date and elapsed number of days

Tags: c#-4.0

I have staring date (suppose 01/15/2013) and also total number of days (suppose 395 days) elapsed from starting date (end date will come as 02/13/2014). Now how can I calculate how many months are there in these many days.

Comment: Relevant/useful: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx

Comment: what is your definition of "month" ?

Comment: +1 to Xaruth's question. You need to define what you mean by 'how many months are between these dates'. Starting at 31st January, with a duration of 1 day, gives an end date of 1st February - but is that one month or zero?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your definition of months you can do just `Math.Ceil(days / 30)` or `Math.Floor(days / 30)`.

You can loop adding months to `from` Date:

```
DateTime from = new DateTime(2013, 01, 15);
DateTime to = from.AddDays(395);
var months = 0;
var date = from;

while(date <= to)
{
    ++months;
    date = date.AddMonths(1);
}
```

A different trick is to do:

```
DateTime diff = DateTime.MinValue + (to - from);

// note: MinValue is 1/1/1 so we have to subtract...
var years = diff.Year - 1;
var months = diff.Month - 1;

months += years * 12;
```

Comment: 'System.TimeSpan' does not contain a definition for 'Months'

Comment: you changed for 'TotalDays'. Well, it's 395, isn't it ?

Comment: Sorry, got confused. Proper answer is in place ;-)

Comment: What if you add 60 days ? Some years, 'to' will be february 29th, other years, 'to' will be march 1st. Or starting July 1st and adding 62 days ? Using MinValue doesn't ensure you have the good value with second solution. First solution might be a correct method.

Comment: @Xaruth - yes, it all depends what is the definition of month and what precision is required.